# Capture errors during Silent Install NSIS?

Tags: nsis

For NSIS installer with UI, we can see the error as a popup while doing the installation.
[image]

But how about Silent install. How do we know if an error happened during silent install ? Is there an error handler that we can make use of ?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the installer: `IfErrors` and/or `.onInstFailed`.

Outside of the process: The process exit code is not 0 (1 is usually user abort).